# Does Corruption/Crimson/Hallow Spread on a Multiplayer Server when no-one is logged on?

Tags: terraria

Does Corruption/Crimson/Hallow Spread on a multi-player Server when no-one is logged on?

I play on a multiplayer-server (mainly to be able to log on from multiple server) but I am usually the only player. The corruption seems to be spreading overnight when I'm not logged on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The server stops the simulation when no players are connected. Therefore, both the day-night cycle and biome spreads do not proceed unless at least one player is in the world. You can test this for yourself with the "time" command in the server console.